# American woman getting Saudi visa in Abu Dhabi

Tags: visas, us-citizens, saudi-arabia, abu-dhabi

I am traveling to Abu Dhabi and Saudi Arabia.  My business associates in Saudi Arabia suggest that I pick up my visa for Saudi Arabia at the Saudi embassy in Abu Dhabi.

I am an American female, 42 years old.

Is anyone aware of any risks associated with this approach?

Comment: Would you be applying for a business visa?

Comment: To clarify: all visitors to the Kingdom require a sponsor, which is usually arranged months in advance. Have your Saudi associates made these arrangements for your business visa, and are telling you to pick it up when you arrive in the UAE?

Comment: Also female applicants traveling without a male relative to Saudi Arabia need a separate, special permit. Two ladies I know were rejected because they were single.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot walk into the embassy and request a visa (of any type) without a corresponding sponsor in Saudi Arabia. The visa process is entirely electronic; where the authorization is issued online.

So, your business associates have to apply for your business visit visa; once it is approved, they will send you a printout of the approval from the MOFA visa site [`https://visa.mofa.gov.sa/`](https://visa.mofa.gov.sa/).

If you are not a permanent resident of the UAE, then you have to apply for the Saudi visa from your country of citizenship (or permanent residence). Although, there are provisions to apply from UAE (you need to be pre-approved).

All procedures for Saudi visas in the UAE are outsourced to VFS+Tasheel. At their website you'll find [the requirements](https://www.vfstasheel.com/VFSTasheel/html/AE/English/visa_information.jsp) and their [office locations](https://www.vfstasheel.com/VFSTasheel/html/AE/English/service_cen_info.jsp).